# Bigtable Timezone difference in Python SDK vs CBT

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I am testing out Bigtable Python SDK and CBT on my local Bigtable Emulator

I am noticing a difference between the timezones for the SDK and CBT. Both are reading from the same table in the Bigtable Emulator
In the python SDK, it seems to be set to GMT+0 whereas CBT is reading it at GMT+8 (my Malaysian Timezone)
I am trying to figure out why this is the case and how I can ensure both CBT and the SDK reads the same timezone.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to provide some Python code you have used?

Comment: Yeah sure. https://github.com/limjix/GoogleCloudBigDataTest
The file name is testcsvbigtablefilters.py
You might suggest Line 39 is the issue "timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()". But my question is why is it that cbt reads it in my current timezone rather than whats actually in the database and is there anyway to change that? Just out of curiosity

Comment: Sorry for the silence, how did you setup `cbt` to work with the simulator?

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that the cbt command line tool formats the timestamps in your local time zone for display. You can verify this by changing your system clock and rerunning the cbt read command - you'll find that the timestamps have changed to reflect the new time zone.

This doesn't affect how data is stored in the Bigtable - internal timestamps are always microseconds since the Unix epoch, so they are the same regardless of the time zone.